# Using Twilio API In C# how to grab updated status

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, twilio

I've been trying to implement the Twilio API, so far so good. However I'd like to grab some of the elements but I am unable to figure out how to return some of the other parameters. For example I have the following class

```
    public class SMS
{
    public SMS() { 
    }
    // SendSMS though Twilio
    // reference: http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-sms
    public static void SendSMS(string to, string msg, string callbackURL)
    {
        string AccountSid = "abcde";
        string AuthToken = "abcde";
        string from = "+1111111111";

        var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);
        var message = twilio.SendSmsMessage(from, to, msg, callbackURL);

    }
}
```

Currently I just use this class to send the SMS, but I'd like to call the following

```
 message.Status
```

and return this to my controller. Any recommendations on the best way to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT: I am now able to return the string and call it in my controller using

```
Status = SMS.SendSMS("xxxx", Message, "");
```

however I need to have the updated status to check if it is sent, everytime i try this I just get queued instead..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

It looks like your in the right track because you are specifying a Status Callback URL parameter to the SendSmsMessage method.  This lets Twilio tell you when the message status changes by making a request to that URL.  When Twilio calls the Status Callback URL it will includes a SmsStatus parameter with the updated status of the message.

http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-sms#post-parameters-optional

Using the Status Callback is the best method, but it does mean that you won't necessarily be able to return the status from your static method.

Hope that helps.

Devin

Comment: Thanks I'll definitely take a look, appreciate the assistance